# Calling a div class and inserting it inside a div tag of another html file without editing it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

So for example i have this html file  with div element with buttons

```
 <div class="testing">
      <button id="play" onclick="playPause(this.id);">❚❚</button>
      <button id="myTime" onclick="stopTime()">∎</button>
      <button id="mute" onclick="muteVid()">Mute</button>
      <button id="rewindTime" onclick="rewindTime()">◄◄</button>
  </div>
```

And I want to insert it on another html  file inside this div class

```
<html>
<div class="testingTwo">
</div>
</hmtl>
```

The thing is, I don't have access in this htmlTwo file above..

How do i call "testing" class with all of its content (ie buttons) and insert on htmlTwo inside its div class="testingTwo".

Comment: I don't see the javascript code in your example. Improve your question.

Comment: the functions inside those buttons are irrelevant. What I want to achieve here is to insert the div and all of its content inside another html. I don't have access to the html file. I just want to insert it or append it inside the div of the html file. Is this possible?

Comment: Try the answer of @charlietfl. If it is not what you want, I have another idea that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which is a shorthand method of `$.ajax` and allows filtering out fragments of the document being loaded

```
$(function(){
    $('.testingTwo').load('path-to-other-file.html #testing');
});
```

It's not clear which file you have access to. Question is not very clear on that regard

Comment: I have access to the first html file. but i don't have access to the 2nd html file. I want to call the div of the first html file and insert it to the 2nd html file inside its div element.

Comment: Well without having access to  the scripts being loaded in it it's really not clear how you would expect this to work

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Because I have a project for the azure media player, im editing it using the mvc template of visual studio. They want to customize it by adding buttons and watermarks inside the player itself. I have the buttons that works perfectly. but unfortunately, I cant put it inside the player itself.

Comment: I'm Confused...that doesn't sound anything like the question

Comment: It is. My question is just an analogy.. the azure media player is the 2nd html file which i dont have access to. The 1st html is the file which i have access two.

Comment: what you are asking really doesn't make sense then and you should probably look for answers in the player api. Or make your question more specific to what you are really dealing with